# How can I show linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

how can I show this problem? 
A image is attached.

Comment: What do you mean by "show" this problem? You've shown it to us. Is that all you need?

Comment: I mean, prove this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Prove it from the definition of a linear transformation. For a transformation to be linear, it needs to be the case that for any vectors $f$ and $g$ and any scalar $a$, we have

$$S(f)+S(g)=S(f+g)$$
$$aS(f)=S(af)$$

Verify that these properties hold, and you will have your proof.